# Handling a <?php tag in a string (php 5.3)

Tags: php

I'm creating an auto documenter for our APIs. Part of the documentation will be a code example -- pretty much just shows the array of data that should be passed to the API and the curl commands to execute it.

I have this mostly working, but the opening `<?php` is causing me problems. The best thing I've found is to do

```
$code_example = "\n<\?php ... ";
```

I don't have this issue in php 5.5, but our API servers (where this will be running) are on 5.3 at the time being. I don't really like escaping the tag, but it might be the only way I can do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem and how are you handling the string?

Comment: @Devon I'm not sure what you mean. I have a script that generates a string which is a PHP file. This gets stored into our API documentation database, but I either have to escape the opening tag, or the first couple lines get cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question problem is not clear. But maybe you want print code to document.
Try convert your code_example text with function `htmlspecialchar` before print